# Weblink alternative for contacts

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

In Office365/Graph Api you can view messages and events on the office.com Website via the weblink-property. However for contacts it seems to be missing or not implemented.

Is there any equivalent or workaround known for contacts, so a user could view/be redirected to the office.com (or any other Office365 page) webpage and view his contact there?

Comment: If you want this feature too: [Uservoice feature request](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/33965305-contact-api-support-weblink-property-on-contact)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no similar URL property for `Contact`.

I'd suggest adding this to the [Office Developer UserVoice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com). This will ensure it's on the Graph/Exchange team's radar.